# iOS display a UIAlertView with running time

Tags: ios, uialertview, nstimer

I want to log-out from my app after some time without user activity. I found an example how to do this. When the inactivity timer runs out I want to display a pop-up saying "*Logging out in XX secs*" where the seconds will be updating - that is running down: 60, 59, 58 ... and then they reach 0 I'll log out the user (the pop up would also have a "Cancel logout" button which I think is easy to implement.) I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way of creating such a pop-up - seems to me like a fairly common idea, but I could not find anything so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two properties to your private interface:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *logoutAlertView;
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger logoutTimeRemaining;
@end
```

Now, when you show your alert, do it as follows:

```
self.logoutAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                  message:@"Logging out in 60 seconds"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[self.logoutAlertView show];

self.logoutTimeRemaining = 60;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateAlert:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Your `updateAlert:` method would look like this:

```
- (void)updateAlert:(NSTimer *)timer {
    self.logoutTimeRemaining--;
    self.logoutAlertView.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logging out in %d seconds", self.logoutTimeRemaining];

    if (self.logoutTimeRemaining == 0) {
        // actually log out
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is good idea to implement custom `UIAlertView` in this case, and add the  `UILabel` to it  with the timer changing its value

follow my answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228088/customize-uialertbutton-through-layoutsubviews-uialertbutton-class-not-found/15228669#15228669), just add `UILabel` instead of `UIButton` for your case.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples you can refer me to?

Comment: I posted a link to another thread I have recently answered, you could follow  it, it is not difficult to implement what you are looking for. just follow the thread and you will get going.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let you know!

Comment: I used Scott's solution, which suited my needs exactly. Thanks for yours as well

Comment: no problem, yes scott's solution should be quick and affective