# How to add Uibuttons in UIAlertView & UIControlEventTouchUpInside events on Buttons

Tags: ios, ipad

I wants to add UIbuttons on UIAlertView & wants to fire Uibutton events so that i can add another view,in my UIviewcontroller , & ofter that alertbox should be dismiss.

regards
anupam

Comment: Why can't you use default UIAlertView buttons?

Comment: actually i wants to fit design of buttons with Ui of apps .

Comment: Through UIAlertView its not possible, you can find many images of alertview background, just add it over to your view and place buttons as you need and make it work same. Hope this helps you..

Comment: @anupam Please make an effort to ask a better question. Explain your problem in detail, show code examples etc. This is why you are getting negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about adding `UIButtons`  inside `UIAlertView` then you could implement custom `UIAlertView`. [Follow my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228088/customize-uialertbutton-through-layoutsubviews-uialertbutton-class-not-found/15228669#15228669)